# Pass selected checkboxs between pages

Tags: php, javascript, checkbox

I want to pass the values of selected checkboxs between pages. How can I do this ? I think that I have to use JavaScript to get select checkbox values but I don't know how pass to another page the values.

Best Regards

Comment: what are you looking to do?  Is the user submitting a form (perhaps multi-step)?  Is this a preference that you want to take effect immediately and then persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on on which side you want to preserve them. On client side? If so, use session. On clien side? Then use any local storage, like [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/), [HTML5 Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), [DOM Storage](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/javascript-apis/web-storage-dom-storage) etc...

Comment: Please see my reply above to another user ;)

Comment: then it means your user fill the form, **submits** it and then you process the results and send out mail. if so, use session

Comment: Wouldn't it be *server* or *client* side? *User* side ain't nothing.

Comment: sure, it should be. Mistake. fixed

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a PHP session:

```
    <?php
    //start session
    session_start();

    //get the posted values from your form

    $_SESSION['checkbox_value_1'] = $_POST['checkbox_1_name'];
    $_SESSION['checkbox_value_2'] = $_POST['checkbox_2_name'];
    $_SESSION['checkbox_value_3'] = $_POST['checkbox_3_name'];

    ?>
```

So, when you need the values of the checkboxes you can can get the from the session:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['checkbox_value_1'] ?>" name="checkbox_1" />
```

That should do it.

You can also set the checkbox to 'checked' if you add this bit:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['checkbox_value_1']) && $_SESSION['checkbox_value_1'] != ''){
    //is selected (has a value)
    $checkbox_selected = 'checked="checked"';
} else $checkbox_selected = ''; //not checked
?>
```

Then you can write your checkbox like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['checkbox_value_1'] ?>" name="checkbox_1" <?php echo $checkbox_selected; ?> />
```

This will add the checked="checked" attribute to the checkbox.

You could also store these in an array if you want to limit the number of session values. Let me know if you'd like an example of that.

Comment: I need pass the values to another page because I need to send them by email. What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: @brunotiago I'd use a session like I described. Then just call them with your mail function: [PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: When I suggested the possibility of storing it in an array It's because un-checked checkboxes are not sent with form data...you can turn your checkboxes into an array by writing them with array attributes like this: 
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[1]" value="Yes">
<input type="checkbox" name="mailing[2]" value="Yes">
...then use a foreach or reference them directly to print/echo data.

Comment: But I have a session already for the user login. Is that a problem ? I can't start another session ?

Comment: Not a problem - you can just add more session vars. If you only need them temporarily it's a good idea to unset them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you could add get parameter to the form as you post it (so it sets get parameters to the url) representing the checkboxes and then using php to print checked and unchecked boxes according to the last states

for this you would have to catch the submit event of your form via javascript, parse the values of your form's boxes into get-values (many javascript frameworks have support for such operations) and then finally post it to the server, the php on the server then uses the global $_GET variable to test each state when printing the boxes.

(this is a rough idea of an implementation, allways consider unvalidated user parameters could be harmfull for your application)